# Joining an existing git repository

Tags: git

Recently, I installed dual boot on my PC. Earlier I was working on an Android Studio Project on my original OS i.e. Windows. Now somehow (Luckily) the whole C: drive of windows shows up on my new dual boot OS (i.e. Linux Based Elementary OS). I opened the Android Projects directly from c drive onto Android Studio on elementary OS. Then i hit git log and all previous commit were shown which is expected to happen, but i see that git says no changes where committed yet. Android Studio also shows that all files are newly added. Isn't there any way to join the existing git repository?

So that when i join it it will shows already committed files as committed and files yet to be committed and modified and yet to be committed.

Otherwise i think i'll have to keep committing on both OS if i keep switching between OS.

Sorry can't embed images so superuser automatically converted it into a link.

[ScreentShot of `git status` from elementary OS side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYTtJ.png)

[ScreenShot of `ls -l .git` form elementary OS side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AtXM.png)

[ScreenShot of `git log` from elementary OS side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYSMy.png)

This 3rd image clearly shows that there are lots of commit. And git log should actually be saying 4 files modified (and not all files modified)

Comment: Please show a few screenshots from the Linux side, mainly `git status` and `ls -l .git` I guess

Comment: @user1686 I have added screenshots as you asked.

Comment: Looks like they're affected by the `core.autocrlf` mismatch. Can you compare `cat .gitignore | file -` vs `git show :.gitignore | file -` and `git show HEAD:.gitignore | file -`?